# Updating record via REST service

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I'm using the RestSharp API in a C# environment.

I've successfully built code that 1) returns a specific record, and 2) returns the most recent 50 records. As an example, the snippet below is the latter, which is working perfectly:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "/sdpapi/request";
request.AddParameter("OPERATION_NAME", "GET_REQUESTS");

request.AddParameter("INPUT_DATA", @"<operation>
<details>
    <from>0</from>
    <limit>50</limit>
    <filterby>All_Requests</filterby>
</details>
</operation>");
```

What I would like to do is update a single record on the server. The server's API says I must:

1. Provide a "request ID", to specify which record we'll be updating
2. Use an "operation name" of "EDIT_REQUEST"
3. Provide input data like so:

   {
       "operation": {
           "details": {
               "category": "hardware",
               "subject": "test"
       }
   }

**Attempt 1:**

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "/sdpapi/request/{request_id}";
request.AddParameter("request_id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("OPERATION_NAME", "EDIT_REQUEST");
request.AddParameter("INPUT_DATA", @"<operation>
<details>
    <subject>test</subject>
    <category>hardware</category>
</details>
</operation>");
```

Response comes back saying the connection was successful. Server shows a successful update attempt, however no changes are actually made. It's as if it hears my request, thinks I'm updating 0 variables.

**Attempt 2:**

Perhaps it is expecting the input data to be JSON.

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "/sdpapi/request/{request_id}";
request.AddParameter("request_id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("OPERATION_NAME", "EDIT_REQUEST");
request.AddParameter("INPUT_DATA", @"{
    ""operation"": {
        ""details"": {
            ""category"": ""hardware"",
            ""subject"": ""test""
    }
}");
```

This doesn't run. It comes back saying "Error when performing - EDIT_REQUEST - Content is not allowed in prolog."

**Attempt 3:**

I try adding the update parameters via the AddParameter() method.

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "/sdpapi/request/{request_id}";
request.AddParameter("request_id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("OPERATION_NAME", "EDIT_REQUEST");
request.AddParameter("CATEGORY", "hardware");
request.AddParameter("SUBJECT", "test");
```

Returns the error "Error when parsing input XML elements - null - null".

**Attempt 4:**

A suggestion I saw online, to specify the content type and serialize my own JSON.

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(new { category = "hardware", subject = "test" }); 
request.Resource = "/sdpapi/request/{request_id}";
request.AddParameter("request_id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("OPERATION_NAME", "EDIT_REQUEST");
```

Returns the error `"Error when parsing input XML elements - null - null"`.

**Attempt 5:**

```
request.Method = Method.PATCH;
```

I've tried various combinations using Method.PATCH, however it returns the error `"The server does not support the functionality needed to fulfill this request (Method PATCH is not implemented by this servlet for this URI)."`

**Attempt 6:**

```
request.Resource = "/sdpapi/request/{request_id}/category/hardware";
```

I've tried a few combinations of different URLs, however it returns the error `"Error when validating URL - Invalid URL for the requested operation."` Also the in-browser example I have to work with doesn't need to use a fancy URL. While it was a good test, I get the feeling this isn't the right direction.

---

I feel like I'm really close... but after hours of research, I have failed to resolve the matter.

Comment: I have no clue what product you're using but it looks like: https://help.servicedeskplus.com/api/request-operations.html$edit - Have you tried a different format (the note)?

Comment: You solved it! I'm impressed by your investigative work. :) I saw that webpage, but just now found out I was using the wrong format. (Used the one for incident request instead of service request.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this instance was a case of using the wrong format. See Caramiriel's comment above, as they deserve all the credit.